# Android: catching java exceptions within javascript

Tags: android

I have a bunch of java objects that are made available to some javascript code in my Android application via the addJavascriptInterface in the WebView.

However, the problem with this is that when a method call from my java objects results in an exception, it crashes the whole WebView thread. Is there any way I can recieve exceptions arising from java method calls from within javascript code??

for example, is something like this possible in javascript from within Android? If not then is there a specific pattern already available to solve this problem?

```
try{
    javaObject.methodCall(); 
} catch(e) {
  //do something here.
}
```

where `javaObject` is made available to javascript via `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`

Comment: were u able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add a default exception handler to the thread in which the bound object is running, which will call addJavascriptInterface() for the exception object?